# Cross bibliography between files (same for index if possible)

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I'm writing a thesis in Latex.

The structure is as follows:

> one main document, where I go through all the research, meanwhile, another 4 documents (annexes) where all the heavy math is described.

I want to put them all in a single file (pdf file), I don't care about importing annexes as pdf in the main thesis, but I need the bibliography to be only in the main thesis.
This means that the numbering for bibliography citation that annexes use MUST be the same as the bibliography shown in the single, common bibliography.

How can this be accomplished?

Working on a simple latex example to try this, but cant figure how to attach my bib and Tex files.

Comment: In the `main.tex` you can `\include{faa.tex}` and/or `\input{faa.tex}` files. Also, there is `\appendix` command.

Comment: See `xcite` package

Comment: Thanks for your answers. After trying and understanding \include or \input i've got something similar to what i need. Only contra is that i had different preamble for each file, but it worths to get rid of that and getting one single file. I was already using xcite but didnt accomplished to get a common bibliography. On the other hand i'll take a look at appendix, as now im using \tableofcontents.